# Difference between integrating GitHub with Atlassian JIRA Studio and doing it through FishEye?

Tags: github, jira, atlassian-fisheye

What is the difference between integrating GitHub with Atlassian [JIRA Studio](http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/) and doing it through Atlassian Jira Studio plugin [FishEye](http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/)?

Pros/Cons?

Answer (score 1):

Fisheye can be used as "WebSvn" tool and is needed to use for example Crucible for code reviews. In FishEye you can see the commits clearer than in Jira, and you can read the code much easier because of the really good code highlighting

Comment: That is good info but it doesn't tell me anything about the difference. The question is no longer interesting either since Atlassian as of some weeks ago decided to shut down FishEye (and Crucible) and put their functionality into their Git cloud solution BitBucket instead.

Comment: @riper, that sounds like an answer, please post it and self-accept!

Answer (score 0):

FishEye OnDemand currently only supports subversion.  FishEye creates a lot of extra data when working with git and uses an external process for git interaction, things that do not work well with Atlassian's multi-tenant hosted solution.